# Switch between views based on some condition

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am new to angular and ionic, my app information goes like this:  I have a splash screen on which I have my login page,followed by home screen.Now the problem is if the user has logged in once,then whenever the app is closed and opened again it shows the login screen,instead it should show home screen. How do I achieve that. I have tried many solutions, but none of them worked. Kindly help.

```
var kit = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic.service.core', 'ngCordova']);  
kit.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {  

  $stateProvider  
    .state('start', {  
      url: '/',  
      templateUrl: 'templates/start.html',  
      controller: 'StartController'  
    })  
    .state('home', {  
      url: '/home',  
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',  
      controller: 'HomeController'  
    })  
    .state('scrollView', {  
      url: '/scroll',  
      templateUrl: 'templates/ScrollEx.html',  
      controller: 'ScrollExController'  
    })  
    .state('check', {  
      url: '/check',  
      templateUrl: 'templates/check.html',  
      controller: 'CheckController'  
    })  
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');  

});
```

Comment: where do you want to switch your view show that code

Comment: There are multiple ways for doing this depending on your approach. Can you show the login method or your user login strategy.

Answer (score 0):

In your login page's controller, I assume this is `StartController`, you can use something like:

```
// Note you need $location for navigation here:
app.controller('StartController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', /*...*/
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $location /*...*/) {

        // Test condition, just an example:
        if (sessionStorage.user.id) {
            $location.path('/home');
        }

        // Controller code goes here
    });
```

This is assuming you condition is `sessionStorage.user.id`.
Angular's $location will handle router navigation elegantly for you.

*Source*: [AngularJS: $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: Thanks,but it didn't work out,so i used routeProvider instead of stateProvider.

Comment: var app = angular.module("splashModule", ['ngMessages' , 'ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl:'login.html'
        })
        .when('/options',{
            templateUrl:'options.html'
        })                                                                                                       .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });

}]);